SSL error occurs when server used SSL 1.3 and client is Win 10. Is it related to Win version?
I am trying to get a token from an external API using below code using VS2022 and C#. The thing is in with my system, Error raise "AuthenticationException: Authentication failed because the remote party sent a TLS alert: 'ProtocolVersion'."
This exact code on another system raise "IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream." and
on a third system it works without any errors. why is that? I searched a lot in Stack Overflow but none of the solutions works for me. I tried:

Add something to registry
Set ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback
Set SecurityProtocol

Code:
ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate { return true; };
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | 
SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls13 ;

var clientKey = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
{
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", "xxx"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", "xxx"),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials")
});

clientKey.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("client_id", "xxx"));
clientKey.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("client_secret", "xxx"));
clientKey.Headers.ContentType.Parameters.Add(new NameValueHeaderValue("grant_type", "client_credentials"));


var url = "https://auth.xxx.xx/token";

HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
clientHandler.ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback +=
            (sender, certificate, chain, errors) =>
            {
                return true;
            };

var client = new HttpClient(clientHandler);

var task = client.PostAsync(url, clientKey);

task.Wait();

var httpResponse = task.Result;

Added Later
Suddenly I found out the PC that runs the code without error has Win11 and other PCs are on Win 10. What should I do to use an external API with ssl1.3 on Win 10?

TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 are deprecated, so try updating the SecurityProtocol to use TLS 1.2 and 1.3 only.

Thanks but it does not solve my problem. Just tries it
